# Cuándo tipar en typescript y cuándo no?

Tags: typescript

tengo una pregunta teórica que no encontré respuesta en ningún lado.
Cuándo es bueno tipar mis estructuras con typeScript? lo es siempre? por qué?

Comment: Porque si no vas a usar tipado, ya tienes `Javascript`. `Typescript` se inventó precisamente para poder usar tipos :-)

Comment: Eso sería un siempre? @Trauma

Comment: Eso sería un siempre. Si no quieres tipar, JavaScript es tu amigo.

Answer (score 0):

**¿Qué es una estructura de datos y que es un objeto?**

Una estructura de datos no es más que una definición de propiedades/atributos, mientras que un objeto es una estructura de datos pero que además tiene funciones (Como una clase, por ejemplo).

En la practica tanto una estructura de datos como un objeto se pueden representar con clases, la diferencia es que para crear una estructura de datos no se deben implementar métodos según los programadores más puristas (Hay otros programadores que permiten en sus estructuras métodos get-set sin implementar lógica para estos, ya que al implementar lógica estás creando un objeto, pero esto no seria una buena practica de estructura).

**¿Por qué definir tipos de datos para mis estructuras?**

La ventaja de las estructuras de dato es que la persona sepa que dicha estructura siempre le retornará esas propiedades (aunque algunas estén vacías o posean valores por defecto), lo que permite evitar un par de comprobaciones para asegurar que la propiedad existe en el objeto antes de comenzar con el desarrollo de la lógica, del contrario no tiene sentido utilizar estructuras.

Si el lenguaje lo permite estas propiedades siempre deben estar tipadas, para asegurar que el tipo de dato es el adecuado cuando posteriormente se llama en la lógica de tu aplicación.

Imagina este escenario, en tu aplicación un usuario puede tener un objeto de configuración de la aplicación, donde puede configurar muchos parámetros y algunos de ellos son listas(array).

Sin utilizar estructura, utilizando solo objetos tendrás que validar que la propiedad exista para poder guardar en una base de datos o rescatar el valor, además, si no defines la propiedad de ese objeto nunca la tendrá, por lo cual debes siempre guardar las propiedades que configure o no el usuario, del contrario es muy probable que tengas problemas de integridad y para evitar eso habrá un aumento exagerado de validaciones.

Si utilizas una estructura esas propiedades siempre existirán, por lo cual simplemente te encargas de validar el contenido.

Ahora, si estás trabajando con propiedades no tipadas y posteriormente para una propiedad de dicho objeto de configuración necesitas hacer un ciclo de iteración tendrás que validar que realmente sea un objeto iterable, del contrario obtendrás una excepción.

Si utilizas una estructura de datos tipada, podrás iterar sin hacer validaciones de tipo previo, ya que tu estructura te asegurará que tu propiedad siempre será iterable.

**Ventajas del tipado**

Esto en realidad es algo más del lenguaje y se basa en opiniones posiblemente, por lo cual arruinaría mi respuesta, pero si quieres saber cuales son las ventajas de los lenguajes tipados, te invito a revisar el buen amigo google.